# Angular 2+/Auth0 using AuthHttp with a service and observable

Tags: angular, angular2-services, auth0, angular2-observables, authhttp

Trying to convert my Http calls to AuthHttp calls and I get the compile errors listed below when using AuthHttp. I made 2 attempts in solving this and both produced different errors. I would like to preserve the structure I have of having the subscription come from the component and have the service return an observable.

The component that subscribes, the same for both trails.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../hero';

import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

The service, with non related code missing (other functions that have the same issue but I figure if I can get help with one I can figure out the other CRUD functions) i placed both of them uncomented but when I compile I comment one out.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
// import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  ...

  /** GET heroes from the server */
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    // Trial 1
    return this.authHttp.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes, ${this.heroesUrl}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
    );

    // Trial 2
    return this.authHttp
      .get(this.heroesUrl)
      .map((res: Response) => <Hero[]>res.json());
  }

  ...

  constructor(
    // private http: HttpClient,
    private authHttp: AuthHttp,
    private messageService: MessageService) { }
}
```

The errors received

```
// Trial 1
ERROR in src/app/hero.service.ts(36,12): error TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

// Trial 2
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Promise<any>'.
ERROR in src/app/hero.service.ts(44,12): error TS2345: Argument of type '(res: Response) => Hero[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response, index: number) => Hero[]'.
  Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
src/app/hero.service.ts(44,31): error TS2352: Type 'Promise<any>' cannot be converted to type 'Hero[]'.
src/app/hero.service.ts(44,31): error TS2352: Type 'Promise<any>' cannot be converted to type 'Hero[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Promise<any>'.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any assistance is appreciated.

Another question that is related is if I need to pass http options with AuthHttp? here is an example from the service

```
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  /** PUT: update the hero on the server */
  updateHero (hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
    return this.http.put(url, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}, ${url}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
    );
  }
```

I use http here but will swap it out with authHttp and I am not sure if I need the httpOptions anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the map function.
You want something like this:

```
getTenantId (): Observable<string> {
 return this.authHttp.get(this.apiUrl).map(res => res.json());
}
```

More can be found out here...

https://auth0.com/blog/introducing-angular2-jwt-a-library-for-angular2-authentication/